# What color do disabled text-boxes in html uses?

Tags: html, css, colors

my question says it all. I'm interested in the text color and the background color that disabled text-boxes in HTML use ( the entire CSS a disabled text-box use is also welcomed ). I need this so I would match the color settings of some readonly text-boxes with the color of disabled text-boxes in my html page ( don't want them to stick out ).

P.S. I need readonly text-boxes so I can capture events with them.

Comment: The background color for a `disabled` input in chrome is `rgb(235,235,228)` if that helps ..

Comment: In firefox the disabled input background-color is F0F0F0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are whatever you set them to. Only IE9 and older have a fixed, unchangeable setup for disabled elements (which is oddly the only way you can get any kind of `text-shadow` in those versions...)

You can literally do this:

```
:disabled {background-color:pink; color:blue}
```

And get bubblegum-coloured textareas when you disable them!

What I'm trying to say is that you can set the styles to whatever you want, so you could do this:

```
:disabled, :read-only, [disabled], [readonly] {background:#cccccc; color:#ffffff}
```

Comment: Excellent love the flexibility of the solution :) Thanks

Answer (score 17):

The background color is `rgb(235, 235, 228);` or `#EBEBE4` in hex.

At least that's the value in chrome (checked with the debugger tools). This value could be different in other browser

Comment: You should check all of them before posting this - it is a different color in FF 15.0.1

Comment: What about the OP checking them? I told him what I could find and how I found it.

Answer (score 9):

I implemented the following to make any read-only textbox or textarea (useful in my case) appear disabled when it was readonly.

```
<style>
input:read-only, 
textarea:read-only,
[contenteditable]:read-only {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #EBEBE4 !important;
  color: #C6C6C6;
} 
</style>
```

Or this:

```
<style>
input:read-only, 
textarea:read-only,
[contenteditable]:read-only {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #EBEBE4 !important;
  color: #C6C6C6;
}
</style>
```

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Good answer, but be aware the style of disabled elements is browser-specific, so this might not work across all browsers.

Comment: Thankyou noted! I will do some research into cross-browser readonly/input properties/styling and if I find anything useful - I'll update my answer!

Comment: I think it might be useful to refer to this if anyone needs information for read-only property styling and cross browser support: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/read-write-read/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browser. In Chrome, it is the system color 'graytext', so you don't need to remember the hex code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's rendered in Chrome:

```
textarea:disabled {
  cursor: default; 
  background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3);
  color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
  border-color: rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My chrome has the following default:

```
background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228);
color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
```

I guess it can change with browser though?